# Spot Fleet Request with KMS-encrypted volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to start Spot instances for my ECS cluster, but I'm struggling to make them start.

The instances always fail to start with `Client.InternalError: Client error on launch`.

According to the documentation, this is because of IAM issues with the EBS volume. I've tried to give as many permissions as possibles to both the fleet role and the instance role (I think it's the latter which matters, but I'm not even sure). Nothing seems to work, I'm a bit lost.

I've tried to make an MRE, sorry if it's a bit long, I don't think a can really make it shorter.

```hcl
### IAM

resource "aws_iam_role" "fleet" {
  name = "ecs-fleet"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode(
    {
      "Version" : "2008-10-17",
      "Statement" : [
        {
          "Sid" : "",
          "Effect" : "Allow",
          "Principal" : {
            "Service" : [
              "spotfleet.amazonaws.com",
              "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            ]
          },
          "Action" : "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
      ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs" {
  name = "ecs.role"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "ecs" {
  name = "ecs.profile"
  role = aws_iam_role.ecs.name
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "fleet" {
  name       = "ecs-fleet"
  roles      = [aws_iam_role.fleet.name]
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2SpotFleetTaggingRole"
}

### KMS

resource "aws_kms_key" "default" {
  policy = jsonencode(
    {
      "Version" : "2012-10-17",
      "Id" : "key-default-1",
      "Statement" : [
        {
          "Sid" : "Allow service-linked role use of the customer managed key",
          "Effect" : "Allow",
          "Principal" : {
            "AWS" : [
              aws_iam_role.ecs.arn,
              aws_iam_role.fleet.arn,
            ]
          },
          "Action" : [
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:ReEncrypt*",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
            "kms:DescribeKey"
          ],
          "Resource" : "*"
        },
        {
          "Sid" : "Allow attachment of persistent resources",
          "Effect" : "Allow",
          "Principal" : {
            "AWS" : [
              aws_iam_role.ecs.arn,
              aws_iam_role.fleet.arn
            ]
          },
          "Action": [
              "kms:CreateGrant",
              "kms:ListGrants",
              "kms:RevokeGrant"
          ],
          "Resource" : "*",
          "Condition" : {
            "Bool" : {
              "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource" : "true"
            }
          },
        }
      ]
    }
  )
}

### Spot

resource "aws_launch_template" "ecs_c6i" {
  name = "ECS-c6i.xlarge"
  image_id      = "ami-00f05e43221bf6048" # al2022-ami-ecs-hvm-2022.0.20220630-x86_64-ebs
  ebs_optimized = true
  instance_type = "c6i.xlarge"

  iam_instance_profile {
    name = aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs.name
  }

  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/xvda"

    ebs {
      kms_key_id = aws_kms_key.default.arn
      volume_size = 30
      delete_on_termination = true
      encrypted = true
      volume_type = "gp3"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_spot_fleet_request" "main" {
  iam_fleet_role = aws_iam_role.fleet.arn
  allocation_strategy                 = "lowestPrice"
  target_capacity                     = 1
  terminate_instances_with_expiration = false

  launch_template_config {
    launch_template_specification {
      id      = aws_launch_template.ecs_c6i.id
      version = "$Latest"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I eventually found it. It wasn't the fleet role nor the instance role which needed the KMS access, but the service role.

So I had to add `"arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/aws-service-role/spotfleet.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForEC2SpotFleet"` to `Allow service-linked role use of the customer managed key` and `Allow attachment of persistent resources`.

Now it works.